# ¿De qué tipo es el parámetro final en una función variádica?

Tags: go, tipos

He leído acerca de las [funciones variádicas](https://golang.org/ref/spec):

> The final parameter in a function signature may have a type prefixed with `...`. A function with such a parameter is called variadic and may be invoked with zero or more arguments for that parameter.

Traducido:

> El parámetro final en una signatura de función puede tener un tipo con el prefijo `...`. Una función con un parámetro de ese tipo se llama *variadic* y puede ser invocado con cero o más argumentos para ese parámetro.

Entonces, es válido:

```
func Zoológico(ación string, animales ...string) {
   // ...
}
```

Pero, ¿cuál será el tipo de `animales`? ¿Es un `string`, o `[]string`, u otra cosa "especial"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El tipo del parámetro especificado con `...T` será de tipo `[]T` tal como indica [la especificación](https://golang.org/ref/spec) en la sección *Passing arguments to ... parameters*:

> Si `f` es variádica con un parámetro final `p` de tipo `...T`, dentro de `f` el tipo de `p` es equivalente a `[]T`. Si `f` se invoca sin parámetros en `p`, el valor asignado a `p` es `nil`. En otro caso, el valor pasado es un nuevo *slice* de tipo `[]T` con un nuevo array subyacente cuyos elementos son los argumentos de la función, que han de ser asignables a `T`. La longitud y capacidad del *slice* es pues el número de argumentos asociados a `p` y puede ser diferente en cada lugar de llamada.

La versión original de este párrafo dice:

> If `f` is variadic with a final parameter `p` of type `...T`, then within `f` the type of `p` is equivalent to type `[]T`. If `f` is invoked with no actual arguments for `p`, the value passed to `p` is `nil`. Otherwise, the value passed is a new slice of type `[]T` with a new underlying array whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to `T`. The length and capacity of the slice is therefore the number of arguments bound to `p` and may differ for each call site.

Comment: **Nota**: He dejado *slice* sin traducir en la cita de la especificación puesto que el significado dentro del lenguaje es bastante concreto y no sabría traducirlo sin que pierda parte de su semántica (y por tanto confunda a futuros lectores).